# Resizing an Image in Java 7

Tags: java, image, resize, game-engine, resolution

So I am making a video game about kittens, and I am doing the art for the player. Well, I like drawing in 16x16 but I prefer the image to be 64x64 on the Java window. This is how I make the Image instance:
`Image player = new ImageIcon("res/player.png").getImage();`
And I have already tried this, but it doesnt work:
`player.getScaledInstance(64, 64, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);`
For some reason this doesnt work when it has worked for everyone else. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

// EDIT: ANSWER FOUND
When I drew the Image with Graphics, I should have said g.drawImage(player.player, 0, 0, 64, 64, this);

Comment: How doesnt it work? Any errors? What was the expected outcome?

Comment: I think [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: *"EDIT: ANSWER FOUND"*  1) Don't SHOUT at us.  2) Don't edit answers into questions.  -- If you've solved it, either delete the question or answer your own question in an (actual) answer.